# How to cleanup Wordpress media tags after migration?

Tags: migrations

After migrating from Wordpress to Drupal with the [Wordpress Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) and [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) modules, content still contains media tags:

```
[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_large","fid":"4202","attributes":[{"class":"media-image","typeof":"foaf:Image","style":"","width":"339","height":"305"}]}]]
```

What is the best way to strip them out?

Comment: I have *exactly this question*.  It is *not* too broad, but its formulation is sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

Ah found the answer after some digging:

> You have the Media module enabled, so the migration renders image references as media tags - you need to change your filter to interpret the tags

http://drupal.org/node/1859458#comment-6819442

> You have the Media module enabled, correct? And you're saying when you view (not edit) the nodes you're seeing the media embeds ([[{"type":"media"," etc.) instead of the image itself? Please go to /admin/config/content/formats and make sure that the text format you've chosen for the imported bodies has "Convert Media tags to markup" enabled.

http://drupal.org/node/1642352#comment-6136596

- http://drupal.org/project/media